# web scraping without id

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need help about web scraping. Here is the html example:

```
<div class="content" name="content-name">
   <h2 class="Topic">First Topic</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>This Data 1</li>
      <li>This Data 2</li>
      <li>This Data 3</li>
   </ul>
   <h2 class="Topic">Second Topic</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>That Data 1</li>
      <li>That Data 2</li>
      <li>That Data 3</li>
   </ul>
   <h2 class="Topic">Third Topic</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>Their Data 1</li>
      <li>Their Data 2</li>
      <li>Their Data 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Using BeautifulSoup, I could get the html div tag for name="content-name". But how do i get all text with **li** tag inside **ul** after **h2** tag that have "second topic" text? Because all of that is in the same div tag without specific class,id,or name.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = """
<div class="content" name="content-name">
    <h2 class="Topic">First Topic</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>This Data 1</li>
        <li>This Data 2</li>
        <li>This Data 3</li>
    </ul>
    <h2 class="Topic">Second Topic</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>That Data 1</li>
        <li>That Data 2</li>
        <li>That Data 3</li>
    </ul>
    <h2 class="Topic">Third Topic</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Their Data 1</li>
        <li>Their Data 2</li>
        <li>Their Data 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

content = soup.find_all("div", class_="content")[0]


second_topic = content.find_all("h2", class_="Topic", string="Second Topic")[0]

ul = second_topic.next_sibling.next_sibling

li = ul.find_all("li")
for i in li:
    print(i.string)
```

Comment: I would prefer ul = second_topic.find_next_sibling('ul') which is more robust

Comment: Except that, I prefer your solution

Comment: you are right, not sure why I used next sibling, guess I just wanted to make OP aware it existed

Comment: My solution is quite rough and not really what you would write in practice (creates so many variables). I just wanted to show him how it works

Comment: I mean I prefer the solution which finds the good h2 before searching ul (which is yours)

Answer (score 2):

It is always more difficult when tags don't have ids or classes or parent tags.

You can use [find_previous_sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div class="content" name="content-name">
   <h2 class="Topic">First Topic</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>This Data 1</li>
      <li>This Data 2</li>
      <li>This Data 3</li>
   </ul>
   <h2 class="Topic">Second Topic</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>That Data 1</li>
      <li>That Data 2</li>
      <li>That Data 3</li>
   </ul>
   <h2 class="Topic">Third Topic</h2>
   <ul>
      <li>Their Data 1</li>
      <li>Their Data 2</li>
      <li>Their Data 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for ul in soup.find_all('ul'):
    if ul.find_previous_sibling('h2').text == 'Second Topic':
        for li in ul.find_all('li'):
            print(li.text)
```

Returns

```
That Data 1
That Data 2
That Data 3
```

Comment: Do u mean find_next_sibling?

Comment: @laurentiuskevin Nope